# shared_buffers settings for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

My `shared_buffers = 128MB`, i.e., the default. I have 120 GB of memory in my Linux machine ([CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)).

To achieve the better performance on user queries,  How much I can change the shared_buffers.

If I change `shared_buffers` what else i need to consider.

My setup:

`max_wal_size = 5GB` 
`# archive_mode =off` in the `posrgresql.conf` file.

Is there anything I could do to improve the query performance?

Comment: Wrong forum, and too little information. How big is your database? OLTP or OLAP? Transactions per second? Read/write ratio? How much WAL per hour? etc.

Comment: thank for reply , DB is 1 TB.  it is OLAP , we do one time load every day with night running jobs. But, we have around 50 users running complex select queries for reporting purpose

Answer (score 1):

I would set it to 30GB, but you can also play with 90GB. Don't set it to 60GB (half your RAM) to avoid double buffering.

I would prefer a lower setting so that I can set `work_mem` very high for good query performance without running out of memory. After all, the "unused RAM" is also used to cache PostgreSQL data.

Define enough [huge pages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-HUGE-PAGES) in the kernel to contain `shared_buffers`.

Comment: What do you mean with `"unused RAM"`? For example; in this case(I just push the limits) the shared_buffers is 30 GB, work_mem 500 MB and max_connections is 100. If all the sessions utilize the all of the work_mem(let' s assume we do not use hash_multiplier due to has join), so in that case 30 GB + (500 MB * 100) = 80GB. For those processes spill to disk will use local temporary areas, but what happens that 40 GB?